# There is already an oped DataReader associated with this Connection

Tags: vb.net

I need some help, i can't solve this error...i watched other topics, but i didn't understand.

"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection ..."

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnCautaNumeClient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCautaNumeClient.Click
    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=multimedia_rent_project"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String = "select ... bla bla bla;"
        myCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)

        If txtIntroducetiNumeleClientului.Text.Length = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No input!")
        Else
            Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            Dim nr As Integer = 0
            While myReader.Read
                nr += 1
            End While

            If nr = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No client find!")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Client found!")
                SDA.SelectCommand = myCommand
                SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
                bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
                cautaClientiDupaNume.dgwCautaClientiDupaNume.DataSource = bSource
                SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

                cautaClientiDupaNume.Show()
            End If
        End If

        MySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the loop that counts the record add a call to Close

```
        While myReader.Read
            nr += 1
        End While
        myReader.Close()
```

The reason of this error is due the fact that when a connection is used by a DataReader it cannot be used for other database commands until you close the reader.
In your code you open the reader to count the number of records retrieved but then you proceed to use the same connection (associated to the command) to fill a dataset without closing the reader.

Said that, I think you should change your code to avoid the MySqlDataReader because you are using it just for counting the records retrieved. If this is your only requirement then it is better to use the SQL Function COUNT()

```
    Dim Query As String = "select COUNT(*) FROM table where .."
    myCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
    Dim nr = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar())
```

Of course, having changed the commandtext of the command to just count the records, then you need to reset the commandtext to its previous value (the .... bla bla bla part ...)